# Can we preserve garlic and ginger paste?

Tags: garlic, ginger

Its mostly said that we should use fresh garlic and ginger paste as after some time the paste loses its taste? So what’s the best way to preserve it, so that its taste is not lost?

Comment: Madiha sabir, welcome to Seasoned Advice! Please note that questions about health and explicitly excluded here. You may ask about preserving the taste. The [tour] and our [help] explain more about how the site works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've had success freezing it in an ice cube tray. The tray should then be sealed in a bag or box, and you won't want to use it for anything else afterwards - I've never found a way of getting rid of the smell.

If you always use it in larger quantities than one or two ice cubes, by all means freeze it in larger containers, but expect to defrost and use the entire container.